# How can I call an async rust function from a synchronous Java function via JNI?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rust, async-await

I am currently trying to run an async function inside of Java with the Rust JNI crate. I was wondering if there was a way to run an async task `foo.async` under a sync function. This is to run async in Java. So basically I need a `fn` to run an `async fn`.

```
package quest.evo.runtime

import quest.evo.runtime.objects.MainWorker
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

object Library {
    external fun create_main_worker(): MainWorker;

    init {
        val tempDir = File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))
        try {
            if (tempDir.exists()) {
                val os = System.getProperty("os.name")
                val extension = if (os.startsWith("Windows")) ".dll" else if (os.startsWith("Mac OS")) ".dylib" else ".so"
                if (tempDir.canWrite()) {
                    val file = File(tempDir, "libevo$extension")
                    file.delete()
                    file.createNewFile()
                    try {
                        Library::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("libevo$extension").use { inputStream ->
                            FileOutputStream(file.absolutePath).use { outputStream ->
                                val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                                if (inputStream != null) {
                                    while (true) {
                                        val length = inputStream.read(buffer)
                                        if (length == -1) {
                                            break
                                        }
                                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                    }
                    System.load(file.absolutePath)
                } else {
                    println("Cannot write to the temp directory.")
                }
            } else {
                println("Cannot find the temp directory.")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val test = create_main_worker();
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine you’ll need to use a dedicated thread - otherwise you’ll run the risk of deadlocking your process.

Comment: Please post your current Java code.

Comment: You cannot, because you need an async runtime. At the very least you need a `Context` & `Waker` to pass to your async  fn.

Comment: @Dai it's in Kotlin, but compiles to JVM.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/icelamejiy.kotlin

Comment: @CarterDavis put your code directly in your SO post, don’t use external websites.

Comment: It's too long though. @Dai

Comment: @CarterDavis I added it for you now - I don't know why you say it's too long, it fits fine.

Comment: @CarterDavis You really shouldn't be swallowing and ignoring exceptions...